# How to describe type for a generic component export in flowjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm upgrading code to types-first and stuck upon need to explicitly declare type of generic react component via flowjs annotations

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
 
type P<TArg> = {
    items: TArg[],
    onSelect: (props: TArg) => void
}

type Item = {
    key: string
}

class Autocomplete<TElem: Item> extends React.Component<P<TElem>> {

}

//its external function provided via import, i put it here for simplicity
function woodoo<F>(v: F): F {
    return v
}
```

If i try to export result of calling the function:

```
export default woodoo(Autocomplete)
```

I will get following error:

> Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Cannot determine the type of this call expression. Please provide an annotation, e.g., by adding a type cast around this expression.Flow(signature-verification-failure)

If I try to export it via component:

```
export default (woodoo(Autocomplete): Autocomplete)
```

I will get following error:

> Cannot use  `Autocomplete` [1] without 1 type argument.Flow(missing-type-arg)

I know export should be more like

```
export default (woodoo(Autocomplete): React$ComponentType<????>)
```

but idk what to put in angle backets to achieve proper typing.

Making the component covariant instead of generic is not valid since the expected value passed in `onSelect` function is exactly the same that provided via `items` property and usage of covariance would not yield the same level of strictness as usage of generic would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
export default (woodoo(Autocomplete): typeof Autocomplete);
```

I got this answer straight up from using vscode using the quick fix feature
[image: using quick fix on vscode]

Answer (score -1):

The easiest approach is to hover the component, check it type, and fill at the export.

Anyway you can try:

```
export default (woodoo(Autocomplete): React.Element<typeof Autocomplete>)
```

Comment: It results in following error: Cannot cast `woodoo(...)` to `React.Element` because property `key` is missing in  statics of `Autocomplete` [1] but exists in  object type

Comment: Please make a reproducible example in the playground tool

Comment: playground seems like have types first disabled , see this -https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28AUqoDmAlHALwB8cA3gFBz1xTAzpQB2c+BNAvkA    So its impossible to reproduce via playground, only with actual tool

Comment: You can try making a codesandbox with flow

Comment: I have no idea how this can be done, all examples i found either wasnt using flowjs or somehow had typescript 'working' - for example this https://codesandbox.io/s/rllozorqv4?file=/src/App.js, i cant flowjs even on homepage, when creating sandbox...